# Convert String to Date

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am using content syndication to parse through an RSS feed to display content in an email newsletter. Part of the logic in the template will require to only show content if it's less than 7 days old. However the date on the RSS feed is in the following format: 
**Thu, 30 Oct 2014 11:00:06 +0000**

Is there a way to convert this to a date format that AMPscript can read?

Comment: Have you tried the `DateParse` function? http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/datetime_ampscript_functions/

It isn't clear which date formats it can parse from the documentation.

Comment: It's not sexy, but if the StringToDate function doesn't work (http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#StringToDate), you may have to use SubString+Concat+StringToDate to generate a date value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously mentioned, both the `DateParse()` and `StringToDate()` functions will work.

```
%%[

var @dateStr
set @dateStr = "Thu, 30 Oct 2014 11:00:06 +0000"

]%%

<br>dateStr : %%=v(@dateStr)=%%
<br>DateParse: %%=DateParse(@dateStr)=%%
<br>StringToDate: %%=StringToDate(@dateStr)=%%
```

**Output**

```
dateStr : Thu, 30 Oct 2014 11:00:06 +0000 
DateParse: 10/30/2014 5:00:06 AM 
StringToDate: 10/30/2014 5:00:06 AM
```